# measure cuda execution time with respect to number of blocks

Tags: c, performance, cuda

I wrote my first cuda script and wonder about how it is parallelized.
I have some variables `r0_dev` and `f_dev`, arrays of length `(*fnum_dev) * 3` each. On each block, they are read sequentially. Then there are `r_dev`, which I read, and `v_dev` which I want to write at in parallel, both are arrays of length `gnum * 3`.

The program produces the results that I want it to produce, but the complexity (function of time with respect to data size) is not what I would have expected.

My expectation is, that, when the size of the array `v_dev` increases, the execution time stays constant, for values of `gnum` smaller than the number of blocks allowed in some dimension.

Reality is different. With the following code, the time was measured. A linear complexity is observed, what I would have expexted in sequential code.

```
dim3 blockGrid(gnum);

cudaEvent_t start, stop;
float time;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

// the actual calculation
stokeslets<<<blockGrid, 1>>>(fnum_dev, r0_dev, f_dev, r_dev, v_dev);

// time measurement
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
```

**Question:**

Is my expectation, described above, wrong?
What additional considerrations are important?

**Details**

The following shows the implementation of `stokeslet`. Maybe I'm doing something bad there?

```
__device__ void gridPoint(int offset, float* r0, float* f, float* r, float* v) {
    int flatInd = 3 * offset;

    float dr[3];
    float len = 0;
    float drf = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        dr[i] = r[i] - r0[i + flatInd];
        len += dr[i] * dr[i];
        drf += dr[i] * f[i + flatInd];
    }

    len = sqrt(len);
    float fak = 1 / (8 * 3.1416 * 0.7);
    v[0] +=  (fak / len) * (f[0 + flatInd] + (dr[0]) * drf / (len * len));
    v[1] +=  (fak / len) * (f[1 + flatInd] + (dr[1]) * drf / (len * len));
    v[2] +=  (fak / len) * (f[2 + flatInd] + (dr[2]) * drf / (len * len));
}


__global__ void stokeslets(int* fnum, float* r0, float* f, float* r, float* v) {
    // where are we (which block, which is equivalent to the grid point)?
    int idx = blockIdx.x;

    // we want to add all force contributions
    float rh[3] = {r[3 * idx + 0], r[3 * idx + 1], r[3 * idx + 2]};

    float vh[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    for (int i=0; i < *fnum; i++) {
        gridPoint(i, r0, f, rh, vh);
    }
    // sum intermediate velocity vh
    int flatInd = 3 * idx;
    v[0 + flatInd] += vh[0];
    v[1 + flatInd] += vh[1];
    v[2 + flatInd] += vh[2];
}
```

Comment: What range of gnum values did you test with?  Timer precision may be an  issue for short-running kernels; what was the longest time you measured?

Comment: the values for time were between 100 and 3000, it's millisecond, I think, and the precision should be around 0.5 milliseconds.

Comment: You are running multiple blocks containing only one thread. Remember that the threads in a block are organized in warps of `32` threads and executed concurrently. In your case, you are wasting the GPU parallelism since you are running warps with only one thread. I would recommend you to rewrite your code/kernel, enabling threads concurrency.

Comment: If you are new to CUDA, to have more information on threads organization and scheduling I would suggest you to go through: [Streaming multiprocessors, Blocks and Threads (CUDA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519598/streaming-multiprocessors-blocks-and-threads-cuda), [How CUDA Blocks/Warps/Threads map onto CUDA Cores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460742/how-cuda-blocks-warps-threads-map-onto-cuda-cores) and [the Fermi architecture whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf).

Comment: @JackOLantern when you write an answer, I accept it :). The word warp is new to me. Probably my view of parelellism was far to naive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with you code is that **you are running multiple blocks containing only one thread**.

Quoting the CUDA C Programming Guide

> The NVIDIA GPU architecture is built around a scalable array of multithreaded
>   Streaming Multiprocessors (SMs). When a CUDA program on the host CPU invokes a
>   kernel grid, the blocks of the grid are enumerated and distributed to multiprocessors
>   with available execution capacity. The threads of a thread block execute concurrently
>   on one multiprocessor, and multiple thread blocks can execute concurrently on one
>   multiprocessor. As thread blocks terminate, new blocks are launched on the vacated
>   multiprocessors.
>
> A multiprocessor is designed to execute hundreds of threads concurrently.

Quoting the answer to the post [How CUDA Blocks/Warps/Threads map onto CUDA Cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460742/how-cuda-blocks-warps-threads-map-onto-cuda-cores)

> The programmer divides work into threads, threads into thread blocks, and thread blocks into grids. The compute work distributor allocates thread blocks to Streaming Multiprocessors (SMs). Once a thread block is distributed to a SM the resources for the thread block are allocated (warps and shared memory) and threads are divided into groups of 32 threads called warps. Once a warp is allocated it is called an active warp. **The two warp schedulers pick two active warps per cycle and dispatch warps to execution units**.

From the two bold-marked sentences, it follows that **you have only 2 threads running per clock cycle per streaming multiprocessor**. This is the main reason why you are observing essentially the same computational complexity as for the sequential case.

The recommendation is to rewrite your code/kernel to host the possibility to run multiple threads per block.

Further readings: [The Fermi architecture whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf).