# For CUDA, how many sp are allocated to the 32 threads of warp in CUDA for execution?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

At present, I understand that the threads in a block will be divided into multiple warps, and these warps will run on one SM. This is because the warps in a block need to work together. But specifically in SM, according to what logic are the 32 threads of one warp allocated to how many SPs for execution? Is 1 SP only execute 1 thread at the same time?

Do GPUs of different periods and architectures have different answers to the above questions?

In SM, according to what logic are the 32 threads of one warp allocated to how many SPs for execution? Is 1 SP only execute 1 thread at the same time?

Comment: Each SM has between 1-4 SM partitions (all the recent architectures have 4). Each SM partition has a number of execution units for different types of instructions. SP is a marketing term and typically used for floating point performance. The execution units are switched between different resident warps residing on the SM partition. The instructions are executed on them in an overlapped way (pipelining). Depending on the number of execution units per SM partition (e.g. 16 or 32) each thread in a warp is assigned a different float execution unit or two threads are executed one after the other.

Comment: See also https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-the-16-int-cores-in-a-processing-block-in-sm-execute-when-32-integers-in-a-warp-is-calculated/259827 (How the 16 int cores in a processing block in SM execute when 32 integers in a warp is calculated?)

Comment: See [Greg Smith's answer to "Streaming multiprocessors, Blocks and Threads (CUDA)"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191977/10107454).